# Cypress: How to add functions to Mocha Context?

Tags: cypress

I am trying add functions to `this` (which is a Mocha `Context`) in tests, so I can do e.g.

```
describe('my spec', () => {
  it('should work', function () {
    this.sayHelloWorld();
  })
})
```

In an empty folder I call

```
yarn add cypress
yarn cypress open
```

so that default config files are created. It also creates a sample test in `cypress/e2e/spec.cy.js`.

I can run the sample test without problem. But if I add

```
import { Context } from "mocha";
```

to `cypress/support/e2e.js` I get

```
Error: Webpack Compilation Error
./cypress/support/e2e.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'mocha' in '...\support'
resolve 'mocha' in '...\support'
  Parsed request is a module
```

So I installed Mocha, the same version which is in devDependencies of Cypress (see [package.json](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/blob/develop/package.json#L188)):

```
yarn add mocha@3.5.3
```

My `package.json` now looks like this:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "cypress": "^10.4.0",
    "mocha": "3.5.3"
  }
}
```

Now that `import` line passes. But this fails:

```
import { Context } from "mocha";

Context.prototype.sayHelloWorld = () => console.log("hello world");
```

Error:

```
> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')
```

Why is that? In comparison adding something to `String.prototype` works.

Also in comparison: Again in an empty folder:

```
yarn add mocha@3.5.3
```

And in `test/test.js`:

```
const { Context } = require("mocha");
it("should work", function () {
  Context.prototype.sayHelloWorld = () => console.log("hello world");
  this.sayHelloWorld();
});
```

Now `yarn mocha` works (says hello world).

What is going on in Cypress? Possibly a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

1. no `import { Context } from "mocha";`
2. add functions like that:

```
Mocha.Context.prototype.sayHelloWorld = function () {
    cy.log('hello world');
};
```